# Unable to delete a file from directory

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm having a few problems deleting a file. Currently I have a listbox that stores the contents of a directory. I'm able to delete the entry from the listbox but not the corresponding file, so when the program is restarted the entry reappears as the file has not been deleted.

This is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //removes selected item from listbox
    foreach (int Index in listBox1.SelectedIndices.Cast<int>().Select(x => x).Reverse())
        listBox1.Items.RemoveAt(Index);

    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(".\\Notes\\");

    //Gets selected listbox item as string
    string fileName = listBox1.GetItemText(listBox1.SelectedItem);

    if (fileName.Equals(files))
    {   // not deleting, yet!
        File.Delete(".\\Notes\\"+ files);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Note deleted!", "ModNote",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
 }
```

Comment: You're comparing a `string` with a `string[]`. That won't work.

Comment: You're also missing the `{ }` after the `foreach` statement. That is probably not behaving as you think it is.

Comment: The two {} are optional, but its not a good code style  to leave them.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your if condition. Instead of

```
if (fileName.Equals(files))
{
    File.Delete(".\\Notes\\"+files);    
}
```

write

```
if (files.Contains(fileName))
{
    File.Delete(".\\Notes\\"+fileName);    
}
```

There are at least two issues: For once, you were comparing a `string` (`fileName`) with a `string[]` (`files`). Additionaly, you were constructing an incorrect path by concatenating ".\Notes\" with the array.